# Python Windows Service to Daemon Service

Tags: python, linux, daemon, pywin32

I have written multiple python windows services, and now I need to port them to Linux.

These services are constantly repeating until an endflag is raised signalling the stoppage of work.  This is just like any service in windows, it implements the start/stop/restart methods using the pywin32 libraries to hook into the windows' framework.  Is there a framework for these command in Linux?  I cannot find any documentation on this.

1. is there a pattern to follow when developing Linux services (daemons)?  If so, where can I find these resources?
2. I know there are many 3rd party packages for Linux Daemon on pypi, does anyone have preferences?
3. Is there a way to see if a service is running on a different Linux box?  Can you start and stop a service on a linux box remotely?
   If you cannot check if a service is running in linux, what I was thinking of doing was creating a server that accepts a variety of commands like:

   - STATUS - informs if a job is running on machine X
   - TURNOFF - ends the service (if it can be done)
   - TURNON - turns the service on a machine (if it can be done)

Sorry for the broad range of questions, but I'm a Linux noob.

Thanks

Comment: Good set of questions as I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of different options, but in general you're going to need to look into the Linux side of things, outside of Python, to decide what makes sense. What Linux distribution you choose also makes a difference as some of them use different service management frameworks by default. I personally tend to like [upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart), it has simple straight forward config files, and is also there by default in Ubuntu. Take a look at this [blog](http://tech.cueup.com/blog/2013/03/08/running-daemons/)(not mine) it gives a great overview of some of the different options.

Welcome to wild world of Linux, it may seem weird at first, but it's really fun!